# Newest Version on Firebase Auth in Flutter Web doesn't work

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

once I try to call `signInWithPhoneNumber()` on flutter web, I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'settings')
at new RecaptchaVerifier (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-auth.js:8390:43)
at RecaptchaVerifier.new (http://localhost:60687/packages/firebase_auth_web/src/interop/auth.dart.lib.js:863:233)
at new firebase_auth_web_recaptcha_verifier_factory.RecaptchaVerifierFactoryWeb.new (http://localhost:60687/packages/firebase_auth_web/src/firebase_auth_web_recaptcha_verifier_factory.dart.lib.js:175:49)
at firebase_auth_web_recaptcha_verifier_factory.RecaptchaVerifierFactoryWeb.__.delegateFor (http://localhost:60687/packages/firebase_auth_web/src/firebase_auth_web_recaptcha_verifier_factory.dart.lib.js:87:14)
at RecaptchaVerifier.new (http://localhost:60687/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart.lib.js:643:94)
at auth_service.AuthService.new.signInUp (http://localhost:60687/packages/qew_app/page_models/welcome_page_model.dart.lib.js:12180:98)
at signInUp.next (<anonymous>)
at runBody (http://localhost:60687/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:60687/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
at auth_service.AuthService.new.signInUp (http://localhost:60687/packages/qew_app/page_models/welcome_page_model.dart.lib.js:12179:20)
at logister_page_model.LogisterPageModel.new.logister (http://localhost:60687/packages/qew_app/page_models/welcome_page_model.dart.lib.js:9060:65)
at logister.next (<anonymous>)
at runBody (http://localhost:60687/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:60687/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
at logister_page_model.LogisterPageModel.new.logister (http://localhost:60687/packages/qew_app/page_models/welcome_page_model.dart.lib.js:9055:20)
at logister_widgets.PhoneNumberCard.new.<anonymous> (http://localhost:60687/packages/qew_app/page_models/welcome_page_model.dart.lib.js:9318:23)
at logister_widgets._PhoneNumberCardState.new.formSubmit (http://localhost:60687/packages/qew_app/ui/views/pages/logister/logister_widgets.dart.lib.js:1543:12)
at http://localhost:60687/packages/qew_app/ui/views/pages/logister/logister_widgets.dart.lib.js:1547:1021
at [_finalizeEditing] (http://localhost:60687/packages/flutter/src/widgets/title.dart.lib.js:36779:9)
at editable_text.EditableTextState.new.performAction (http://localhost:60687/packages/flutter/src/widgets/title.dart.lib.js:36652:39)
at text_input.TextInput.__._handleTextInputInvocation (http://localhost:60687/packages/flutter/src/services/text_formatter.dart.lib.js:2373:66)
at _handleTextInputInvocation.next (<anonymous>)
at runBody (http://localhost:60687/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:60687/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
at [_handleTextInputInvocation] (http://localhost:60687/packages/flutter/src/services/text_formatter.dart.lib.js:2288:20)
at OptionalMethodChannel._handleAsMethodCall (http://localhost:60687/packages/flutter/src/services/restoration.dart.lib.js:1599:57)
at _handleAsMethodCall.next (<anonymous>)
at runBody (http://localhost:60687/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:60687/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
at [_handleAsMethodCall] (http://localhost:60687/packages/flutter/src/services/restoration.dart.lib.js:1596:20)
at http://localhost:60687/packages/flutter/src/services/restoration.dart.lib.js:1593:126
at http://localhost:60687/packages/flutter/src/services/restoration.dart.lib.js:6148:31
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at runBody (http://localhost:60687/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:60687/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
at http://localhost:60687/packages/flutter/src/services/restoration.dart.lib.js:6145:82
at Object.invoke2 (http://localhost:60687/dart_sdk.js:191758:7)
at ui._ChannelCallbackRecord.new.invoke (http://localhost:60687/dart_sdk.js:133047:15)
at ui._Channel.new.push (http://localhost:60687/dart_sdk.js:133118:54)
at ui.ChannelBuffers.new.push (http://localhost:60687/dart_sdk.js:133209:19)
at _engine.EnginePlatformDispatcher.__.invokeOnPlatformMessage (http://localhost:60687/dart_sdk.js:171990:27)
at _engine.TextEditingChannel.new.performAction (http://localhost:60687/dart_sdk.js:186458:49)
at http://localhost:60687/dart_sdk.js:186537:24
at _engine.GloballyPositionedTextEditingStrategy.new.maybeSendAction (http://localhost:60687/dart_sdk.js:178127:40)
at Object._checkAndCall (http://localhost:60687/dart_sdk.js:5279:16)
at Object.dcall (http://localhost:60687/dart_sdk.js:5284:17)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:60687/dart_sdk.js:109003:100)
```

I'm doing the most basic initialization:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
```

which is generated using flutterfire, and on index.html:

```
<script type="module" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-functions.js"></script>
<script type="module">
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-app.js";
  import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-analytics.js";
  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "secret",
    authDomain: "secret",
    projectId: "secret",
    storageBucket: "secret",
    messagingSenderId: "secret",
    appId: "secret",
    measurementId: "secret"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
}
```

I tried to change the versions to newer ones(even though I'm using older ones deliberately) and a lot of different configuration, and nothing worked:
[js example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XXvY.png)

as you can see in the loaded js module, the authExtern is unidentified.

git issues addressing the subject:

https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9123

https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9124

if someone can think on how to bypass this error, it would be very helpful.

Comment: I have no idea what broke here, but if it only happened in the latest (3.4.2) release: did you consider using the previous release (3.4.1)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've tried, the problem when you install any kind of firebase_auth package it downloads the latest firebase_auth_web which is the problematic

Comment: Got it. I hope somebody gets to it quickly, but expect that may only happen after the weekend.

Comment: Did you get any update on this?